# flipview in a universal windows app

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to add a flipview in my code like this image,
[image]

but I get this result in all pages when I slide in every page:

[image]

this is my code,

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="642">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Style="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, ElementName=grid}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Background="Transparent" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid  Style="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, ElementName=grid}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Background="Transparent" Margin="110,85,10,195" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0"  Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10"  />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"  Background="#2c3389"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10"/>
                            <Button Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1"  Background="#2c3389"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,0,25,27" />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1"  Background="#2c3389"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,0,25,27"  />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid  Style="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, ElementName=grid}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Background="Transparent" Margin="70,85,45,195" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0"  Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10"  />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"  Background="#2c3389"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10"/>
                            <Button Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1"  Background="#2c3389"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,7,25,10" />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1"  Background="#2c3389"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,7,25,10"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
```

have you please any idea how can I correct my code and use the databinding in this case,I work on a universal windows App
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen because you put 2x similar grids close to each other in `ItemTemplate`. `ItemTemplate` define view for each item (each page of FlipView in this case). If you will set `ItemsSource` of FlipView, each item in this collection will exactly copy of ItemTemplate. You can fix your XAML like that:

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,0,25,27" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,0,25,27" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

I removed one grid with buttons and outer grid. Now one page will contains 4 buttons.
You can set `ItemsSource` for you FlipView. `flipView1.ItemsSource = /* collection of models */`

@edit

If you want to use binding and set `Image` in `Button.Content` you will need class which will contains Image sources for each button in single FlipView item. For example:

```
public class ButtonImages
{
    public string Image1 { get; set; }
    public string Image2 { get; set; }
    public string Image3 { get; set; }
    public string Image4 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should prepare collection with objects of this class.

```
var flipViewPages = new List<ButtonImages>();
\\ prepare  your collection - set Image1, Image2.. properties and add these objects to collection
flipView1.ItemSource = flipViewPages
```

Then in XAML you can use `{Binding}`

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="#2c3389" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="22,24,25,10">
    <Image Source="{Binding Image1}" />
</Button>
```

If you need more information about binding you should look for it on other posts and sites. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thanks Sir it works fine,but what about if I want to add in each button in every page a collection of images,should I use :                     <Button.Content>
 <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
</Button.Content>